# Dynamic Strings, AS2, needed on one line

Tags: string, tcp, actionscript-2, ip-address

Ok, so I'm creating a Flash HUD in AS2 that runs on the Surface and connects to our server.

As it stands now, I'm having to hard code the IP addresses for the Surface to connect to, and I'm trying to get past this.

I have 4 text fields for the user to enter the 4 fields of IP address data.  My issue at the moment is that if I set the String variable literally, it works fine. But if I dynamically create the string, instead of outputting on one line, it outputs each of the 4 strings separately.

Here's my code:

```
var newIP1 = getIP.IPtext.IP1.text; //grabbing the data from the UI
var newIP2 = getIP.IPtext.IP2.text;
var newIP3 = getIP.IPtext.IP3.text;
var newIP4 = getIP.IPtext.IP4.text;

var ipArray = new Array(newIP1,newIP2,newIP3,newIP4); //setting the array
trace (ipArray.join(".")); // output the string, replacing the commas with a period
//output: 
//10
//.255
//.255
//.22

//If I do this it works fine
var IPstr = "10.255.255.2";
trace(IPstr);
// output: 10.255.255.22
```

I appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and should work as expected.

One thing to check would be to see if there isn't a carriage return or newline character being added to each individual input box. One way to check would be to check the length of each of your input strings to ensure there isn't an invisible character there.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate further.